# Rewriting url in apache is not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using the following code in .htaccess direct editor in ipage server for changing my website's page url from

for example:

http://foodinger.in/viewRestaurant.php?raipur=Barbecue-Country&id=3006

to

http://foodinger.in/viewRestaurant/raipur/Barbecue-Country

but it is not working

> RewriteEngine on
>
> RewriteRule viewRestaurant/raipur/(.*)/ viewRestaurant.php?raipur=$1&id=$2
>
> RewriteRule viewRestaurant/raipur/(.*) viewRestaurant.php?raipur=$1&id=$2

Am i doing anything wrong, Please anyone suggest me the right way if i am wrong ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify only one group for substitution `(.*)` that will replace `$1` in target url.

Try:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule "^/viewRestaurant/raipur/(.*)/(.*)/?" "/viewRestaurant.php?raipur=$1&id=$2"
```

And query with `Id`: http://foodinger.in/viewRestaurant/raipur/Barbecue-Country/3006

Comment: its still not working please go to http://foodinger.in/restaurants-in-raipur.php?&raipur123acaekufweCEDKJBC2342XzQ&Offers=&Speciality=&filterString=-Dine_Name%20-Area&sort= and then select any restaurant and see the url

Comment: @Aman try to enable mod_rewrite logging (https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteLog) and see what redirection Apache does.